# Android: BLE Gatt Notifications never received

Tags: javascript, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-notifications, gatt

Device used: Galaxy S9, Android 8.0.

Connection is working fine but the `onCharacteristicChangedMethod` of my callback is never called. However I have registered for notifications using `setCharacteristicNotification(char, true)`. Characteristic Notification code:

```
mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Characteristic Config. UUID is `00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`.

Permissions Added to Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I have read that I need to explicitly declare the broadcastReceiver, and observe the following message in the log:

```
W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent
```

Is this the problem, and if so how would I explicitly declare this receiver?

Comment: I have modified my application such that I am no longer implicitly registering a `broadcastReceiver` in Android Manifest; instead, I am using the `registerReceiver()` method  to register a dynamic broadcast receiver within my activity, followed by `unregisterReciever()` to ensure I unregister my subscription based on the activity lifecycle. Unfortunately, this has yielded no change.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this question as whilst declaring the broadcastReceiver dynamically did not enable notifications in my project, it has resolved the issue regarding background execution (which was the original query).